# What exactly does a "significant correlation" mean?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, p-value

I performed the correlation between several variables. R makes it possible to separate significant from non-significant correlations.
I noticed that low corrections (corr=0.4) can be considered significant (p.value<0.05), while non-significant corrections (p.value>0.05) can assume relatively high values (corr=0.7 ).

In this sense, I would like to know what exactly it means to say that one correlation is more significant than another? what arguments could I use to explain the situation above?

Comment: Or here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333137/difference-between-pearsons-r-0-and-p-0-05/

Comment: Sample size matters.

Comment: Try exploring Sklearn's **SelectKBest**. It is a combination of Correlation and F-Test. Mainly, the significance tells you wether the feature and Target variable are coming from the same population or not on top of correlation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is *usually* a test indicating whether one can infer that the "true" (population) correlation is non-zero.
$$
\begin{align}
H_0&: \textrm{The two variables are uncorrelated. } &(r = 0) \\
H_a&: \textrm{The two variables are correlated. } &(r \ne 0) \\
\end{align}
$$

One generally only has access to a sample of values from the two variables of interest. You might imagine that it's easy to infer a strong correlation between two variables from a small sample, but more data is required to determine whether an apparent relationship is a weak correlation or just noise. The formula for the test statistic backs up this intuition: it's a function of the sample size ($n$) and the sample correlation ($r$). One way to test this is via the t distribution. You compute:

$$t^* \approx\dfrac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$

then use the $t_{n-2}$ distribution to convert this into a $p$-value, which tells you the probability of seeing a correlation at least this large in your sample *if the population correlation is zero*. Other approaches use a slightly different "exact" formula, which is again only a function of $r$ and $n$ and can be interpreted in the same way.

Bear in mind that this really tells you *what you can claim*, based on a sample: a large $p$-value does not necessarily mean that the correlation is precisely zero, just that you can't say whether it is/isn't given your data.

This is what Matlab's [`corr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html#bty1g5w-1), SciPy's [`scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr.html?highlight=corr), and R's [`cor.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor.test) by default. There are, of course, other tests one can run on correlations (e.g., to compare two correlations), so check to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you write down the formula for calculating the test statistic, you’ll see that sample size is a factor.

If you have a small correlation value but a large sample size, you can wind up with a small p-value, indicating that there is strong evidence that the correlation is not zero. Even if the true correlation is trivially different from zero, such as $0.01$, that number is not zero.

If you have a small sample size, then you might need a very gigantic correlation value to get the hypothesis test to return a small p-value.

Like all hypothesis testing, sample size plays a huge role in testing correlation.

For further reading, you might want to look into the difference between practical and statistical significance, and you might be interested in equivalence testing.